# Need to add responsiveness to twig file in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-design, twig, timber

I have this function in my tile.twig file that shows one post on a carousel. It works fine on portrait mode on mobile.I need it to show 2 post when it is in landscape. But I do not know how to do this in twig/PHP here is the code:

```
{{ fn("do_action", "render-carousel", style|default('header-carousel'), carousel_list|default("Header Carousel"), img_size|default("mobile/feed/large"), carousel_show|default(1), extra_options) }}
```

I need the carousel_show|default(1) to be carousel_show|default(2) when in landscape mode. Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's difficult, and not performant at all, to "tell" PHP that your device is in portrait or landscape mode, and to render different amounts of HTML accordingly.

I believe you're probably a bit stuck as you're using a plugin to render the carousel and therefore don't have control over the CSS or JS.

If you'd written the carousel yourself. You'd use media queries in CSS:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .carousel-slide {
    width: 50%:
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .carousel-slide {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

You'd also need to tell your carousel code that you're displaying either one or two slides intially:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
  Carousel.init({startingNumberOfSlides:1})
}

if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
  Carousel.init({startingNumberOfSlides:1})
}
```

It sounds like you won't be able to achieve this effect with the carousel plugin you're using.

Thanks,

Jon